# Xmodmap key mapping for a 60% keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

#### Hello, I have this code in my `~/.Xmodmap` file:

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch

keycode  10 = 1 exclam F1 exclam
keycode  11 = 2 at F2 at
keycode  12 = 3 numbersign F3 numbersign
keycode  13 = 4 dollar F4 dollar
keycode  14 = 5 percent F5 percent
keycode  15 = 6 asciicircum F6 asciicircum
keycode  16 = 7 ampersand F7 ampersand
keycode  17 = 8 asterisk F8 asterisk
keycode  18 = 9 parenleft F9 parenleft
keycode  19 = 0 parenright F10 parenright
keycode  20 = minus underscore F11 underscore
keycode  21 = equal plus F12 plus
keycode 24 = q Q grave asciitilde
keycode 43 = h H Left
keycode 44 = j J Down
keycode 45 = k K Up
keycode 46 = l L Right
```

- `Keycode 108` is my Right Alt key, which I substitute as a "makeshift function layer key" *(since my keyboard is not QMK programmable)*

[Here is a visualization of what it does (It's my 60% keyboard layout)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4MeK.png)

All those keys work on their own *(and probably with <kbd>Shift</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifiers though there are inconsistencies)* but not with all possible modifiers like <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Alt_L</kbd>.

> For example:
>
> 1. Trying to use <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd> by pressing <kbd>Alt_R + Alt_L + j</kbd> doesn't work.
> 2. Trying to use <kbd>Super + Left/Down/Up/Right</kbd> *(to move windows)* by pressing <kbd>Super + Alt_R + hjkl</kbd> doesn't work.

**Additionally:** while testing my mappings with an online keyboard tester - the `keycode 108` *(my Right Alt key)* was being interpreted as <kbd>Alt_R</kbd> instead of `Mode_switch`. *(And probably because of this)* My keybinding for arrows, F keys, tilde & backtick were not registering on those websites.

<sub>P.S. I've read through all of the `xmodmap` manpage but I don't know how to solve this issue. And of course I use X11 as my window system. Also this question was happily written with the stated `hjkl` arrow bindings, though it could've been better if my issue was fixed :D</sub>

---

**Edit #1:** My Idea is that editing the modifier table in a clever way I can add the ability to use modifier keys on top of those keybindings. Here is the table:

```
:!xmodmap -pm                                                                                                                                                                                       
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Mode_switch (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

<sub>**Notion:** after applying the key mapping with running the command `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` the <kbd>Alt_R</kbd> key has been erased from the `mod1` string, probably due to assigning `keycode 108 = Mode_switch`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ditched the archaic discombobulating abomination that `xmodmap` is and settled on `keyd` - a small but powerful daemon (perfect example of UNIX philosphy: doing one thing and one thing great). The manpage for `keyd` is much easier to read and it is everything I need for programming my keyboard.